# Airflow cluster: Is it needed to deploy DAGs / Workflows in all the workers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow

We are planning to update Airflow and switch from single Airflow server to Airflow **cluster** (AWS).

We've been cheking the this [article](https://blog.sicara.com/using-airflow-with-celery-workers-54cb5212d405) and [this one](http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/setting-apache-airflow-cluster/).

We are using SQS as queue service and despite the documentation said that we only need to deploy our DAGs py files in the masters we wonder if this is correct.

1. The comunications throught queues don't include the code
2. In our tests, our DAGs are not working in case we don't deploy them in all nodes, workers and masters.

So, what we should do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DAGS need to be synced across all workers for it to work because the `airflow_scheduler` will send the DAG to whichever worker is available. If the DAGS are not synced across all workers, an older copy of the DAG may be run.